# Kubernetes mongodb readiness probe failure

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run the helm chart for mongodb and I am running into readiness / liveness probe issue. The Mongodb helm chart from the stable repository installs the pods and the services. But the pods crash because of the readiness probe. I can try removing them, but I want to know why this is happening.

```
helm install --name mongodb stable/mongodb

kubectl describe pod mongodb-5ff464b5b9-nnz5x

Containers:
  mongodb:
    Container ID:   docker://055f12c14992dc111ee8f0baff7faceafae6a16e518b27a174a7997408235afa
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.0.2-debian-9
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://bitnami/mongodb@sha256:6c050bf9063976e12aabb7bafcc7b2616df1e1dbbf19ac41b4799826abec92a3
    Port:           27017/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Thu, 27 Sep 2018 17:54:01 -0400
      Finished:     Thu, 27 Sep 2018 17:55:50 -0400
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  6
    Liveness:       exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:      exec [mongo --eval db.adminCommand('ping')] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'mongodb-root-password' in secret 'mongodb'>  Optional: false
      MONGODB_USERNAME:       
      MONGODB_DATABASE:       
      MONGODB_ENABLE_IPV6:    yes
      MONGODB_EXTRA_FLAGS:    
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/mongodb from data (rw)
```

In the errors section, I see the following. Do I need to do anything to open the container ports?

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-27T21:43:04.664+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m  kubelet, vm-b768f1df-3df6-4a79-50e5-9af633c6d9b9  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-27T21:43:14.670+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m  kubelet, vm-b768f1df-3df6-4a79-50e5-9af633c6d9b9  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-27T21:43:24.657+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

### Edit 1

Logs from the pod 
I checked the logs, nothing noteworthy

```
`kubectl logs mongodb-5ff464b5b9-nnz5x -p` 
------
Welcome to the Bitnami mongodb container
Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb
Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb/issues

nami    INFO  Initializing mongodb
mongodb INFO  ==> Deploying MongoDB from scratch...
mongodb INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found. Creating default config files...
```

### Edit 2

Ran the same helm chart on GKE and I ran into the exact same issue

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age              From                                                  Message
  ----     ------                 ----             ----                                                  -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling       1m (x4 over 1m)  default-scheduler                                     PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "mongodb-bitnami" (repeated 3 times)
  Normal   Scheduled              1m               default-scheduler                                     Successfully assigned mongodb-bitnami-7b65895fd7-xr6gg to gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m               kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-whl5w"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m               kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-ddda94dd-c2c1-11e8-b2f0-42010af00119"
  Normal   Pulling                1m               kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  pulling image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.0.2-debian-9"
  Normal   Pulled                 39s              kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  Successfully pulled image "docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.0.2-debian-9"
  Normal   Created                38s              kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  Created container
  Normal   Started                37s              kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy              28s              kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-28T01:58:44.936+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
  Warning  Unhealthy  20s  kubelet, gke-cluster-default-pool-bec82955-xmhz  Readiness probe failed: MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-28T01:58:52.114+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not related to whether ports are open or not and looks more like mongo itself is crashing and the readiness probes are failing.

You can find more insights from looking at the logs:

```
kubectl logs <pod-crashing-name> (-c <container-name-optionally)
```

You can also ssh into the nodes where your pods are running an get the docker logs

```
docker ps -a | grep mongo
docker logs <container-id-that-crashed>
```

Comment: I have added the logs above. I couldn't ssh into the container, because there is no container created. kubectl exec -it mongodb-5ff464b5b9-nnz5x -- /bin/bash
error: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("mongodb")

Comment: Not the containers, the nodes (the kubernetes nodes themselves)

Comment: I checked all the node logs (I am running on GCP) and I didn't find any logs which will point to the error. I also ran the same helm chart on GKE and I ran into the exact same issue...just to rule out that it was my cluster.

Comment: I meant the containers in the nodes.  Did you check those with `docker log <container-id>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be an issue with the bitnami helm repo. I remove that from the list of my repos, and used the mongodb from the k8s repo, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is a bug in latest version. I changed my image version to following:

```
  containers:
  - image: mongo:5.0.11
    name: mongo
```

and

[image]

for other images you can see this:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/tags?page=9